# IJCADをvb.netで印刷するときに、印刷領域に窓 (PlotType.Window) を指定するとエラーになってしまう

Tags: vb.net, ijcad

IJCADをvb.netで印刷するときに、印刷領域に窓 (PlotType.Window) を指定すると`icPlSetVdr.SetPlotType(icLayout, GrxCAD.DatabaseServices.PlotType.Window)` のところでエラーになります。

ただし手動で一度印刷領域を窓に設定するとエラーが出なくなります。
最初からエラーが出ないようにする方法はないでしょうか？

```vb
Using icTrans As Transaction = icDb.TransactionManager.StartTransaction()
    Dim icLayMgr As LayoutManager = LayoutManager.Current
    Dim icLayout As Layout = icTrans.GetObject(icLayMgr.GetLayoutId(icLayMgr.CurrentLayout), OpenMode.ForWrite)
    Dim icPlSetVdr = PlotSettingsValidator.Current
    icPlSetVdr.SetPlotType(icLayout, GrxCAD.DatabaseServices.PlotType.Window)
    icPlSetVdr.SetUseStandardScale(icLayout, True)
    icPlSetVdr.SetStdScaleType(icLayout, StdScaleType.ScaleToFit)
    icPlSetVdr.SetPlotCentered(icLayout, True)
    icPlSetVdr.SetPlotRotation(icLayout, PlotRotation.Degrees090)
    icPlSetVdr.SetPlotWindowArea(icLayout, New Extents2d(New Point2d(0.0, 0.0), New Point2d(4000, 2800)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

添付しているコードを少し見ました。エラーというのは、eInvalidInput(code5)ですか？
自分がデバッグしたときはコード上の、
`icPlSetVdr.SetPlotType(icLayout, GrxCAD.DatabaseServices.PlotType.Window)`
というところでeInvalidInput(code5)が起きました。

ちなみにコード最下部の1行を↑のコードよりも前に置くとエラーは出なくなりました。
つまり、

```
Using icTrans As Transaction = icDb.TransactionManager.StartTransaction()
Dim icLayMgr As LayoutManager = LayoutManager.Current
Dim icLayout As Layout = icTrans.GetObject(icLayMgr.GetLayoutId(icLayMgr.CurrentLayout), OpenMode.ForWrite)
Dim icPlSetVdr = PlotSettingsValidator.Current    
icPlSetVdr.SetPlotWindowArea(icLayout, New Extents2d(New Point2d(0.0, 0.0), New Point2d(4000, 2800))) **'ここに追加した**
icPlSetVdr.SetPlotType(icLayout, GrxCAD.DatabaseServices.PlotType.Window) **'ここでエラーが出た**
icPlSetVdr.SetUseStandardScale(icLayout, True)
icPlSetVdr.SetStdScaleType(icLayout, StdScaleType.ScaleToFit)
icPlSetVdr.SetPlotCentered(icLayout, True)
icPlSetVdr.SetPlotRotation(icLayout, PlotRotation.Degrees090)
```

エラーが出る理由はおそらく、コードでなり手動でなり、印刷領域を窓に設定するとその窓のサイズが必要になるので、コードで窓に設定する時に窓のサイズが無いし、又はNULLだとエラーが起きるのではないかと思います。なので、窓に設定するコードの前に窓のサイズを決めてあげるコードを置いてあげると、問題なく動作するのではないでしょうか。

この修正で問題なく動作出来たら、教えてもらえると嬉しいです。

Comment: お返事が遅れて申し訳ありません。ありがとうございます。試してみます。

Comment: ありがとうございます！うまく動作しました！

Comment: お役に立てて良かったです。